# Inkscape - make contour go to the inside

Tags: inkscape

I drew a circle of diameter 100mm and set its contour to be 5mm. Now this means that actual size of that circle is 105mm because it's 100mm for the circle and the contour "overflows" 2.5mm on each side.

Is there an easy way to set it up so that no matter how large contour I set, it will all go to the inside of the circle instead of both sides?

Comment: I don't have Inkscape, but just a shot in the dark: can you set the contour to a negative value?

Comment: Similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/128814/inkscape-how-to-create-inner-border) question. At the moment the border is centered to the path, due to SVG specifications (see also [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/170401)).

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate.  If you do not think this is a duplicate to the other question please make an [edit] with further detail.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 3 step sample pic]

Make your circle (red) without contour. Ctrl-D duplicates it. I moved the duplicate to the right, to make it visible. Make this circle the color of your desired contour (black). Ctrl-D again. Make it yellow. Now with Ctrl-Shift we can resize the yellow circle symetric to the center.

Mark black and yellow circle and choose 'Path', 'Difference'. You should get a hole in the black circle, giving you a contour.

Now group the red circle with the black ring together.